# List of Control Points of Easing Functions

Tags: silverlight, animation, easing-functions

I'm looking for a list or a method to get the `x1, x2, y1, y2` (`KeySpline` equivalent) values of the current **Easing Functions** (for ex: `CircleEase` with mode `EaseInOut`).

How I can get them?

Answer (score 0):

Try the website [easings.net](http://easings.net) , you could click on any easing graph and you will find the control points.